# CI index method/function not automatically added for some cases?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

If we give a method/function's name `index` in codeigniter, we can go to that method without calling it (so we just need to use its `controller` name).

That is because we specify it (or CI specifies it by default) in `config.php` :

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

So when I use some `library` like `form_validation`, I don't need to specify the index method. However, I have a problem when i tried to use the `pagination` class.

I need to specify the `index` method in the code, or the `pagination` doesn't work (it gives a **404** error if I click the next pagination index) :

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend_umat');
```

So, I have to use :

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend_umat/index');
```

And the `pagination` works perfectly.

Please, can anyone kindly give me an **explanation** about what's going on? My **problem** is **solved**, but I'm **curious** about what's going on here.

Thanks :D

Comment: Did u use this `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` for pagination???

Comment: @elavarasanlee yes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter pagination:

- `$config['base_url']` should be the complete url. i.e., `base_url()/{CONTROLLER}/{FUNCTION}`.
- So if you are not giving the complete path, the pagination class will ignore **{FUNCTION}** and will create links like:

> `base_url()/{CONTROLLER}/{PAGE1} , base_url()/{CONTROLLER}/{PAGE2} , 
>    base_url()/{CONTROLLER}/{PAGE3}` and so on... instead of
>   `base_url()/{CONTROLLER}/{FUNCTION}/{PAGE_NO}`

Now in the place of your function there's a number (page number) which is not present in your controller class but is assumed as a function inside your controller. That's the reason you are getting **404 Page Not Found** error.

---

There are two ways to solve this.

1. The way you have done it. `$config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend_umat/index');`
2. Use **routes**.
   Inside your **routing.php** file define this:
   `$route['backend_umat/(:num)'] = 'backend_umat/index/(:num)';`

   In your **controller**: `$config['uri_segment'] = 2;`
   And if you have used: `$this->uri->segment(3)` in your code, make it as `$this->uri->segment(2)`
   That will do.

Comment: Thanks for your concise explanation :D

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you have something after the controller name CodeIgniter cannot differentiate it is a parameter for the index method, it is assumed to be a method. When navigated to the next page something appended to the URL and if there is no method name in the base url it is trying to get the method name from the appended url.

Answer (score 1):

You can route all `backend_umat/` to `index`.

```
$routes['backend_umat/(:any)'] = 'backend_umat/index/$1';
```

OR only if method name is empty, NULL

```
$routes['backend_umat/(^[\s]*$)'] = 'backend_umat/index/$1';

// or JUSt

$routes['backend_umat/(^[\s]*$)'] = 'backend_umat/index';
```

You can add the `routes` configuration in `config/routes.php`.